# How to find the derivative of the function $ \int_{x}^{x^2}\frac{t}{\ln(t)}dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The problem is to find 
$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{x^2}\frac{t}{\ln(t)}\,dt$

I could do this if I had the first clue on how to integrate $\dfrac{t}{\ln(t)}$ but even wolframalpha is giving me a weird answer... some help that makes sense please!

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+y%2Fln%28y%29+dy

Comment: Hint: Define $F(x) = \int_a^x \frac{t}{\ln t} dt$ then $\int_x^{x^2} \frac{t}{\ln t} dt = F(x^2) - F(x)$. Now differentate and use the chain rule.

Comment: I don't see why this question should have been put on hold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's pretend we know that the antiderivative of $\dfrac{t}{\ln t}$ is $F(t)$.

Then, $\displaystyle\int_{x}^{x^2}\dfrac{t}{\ln t}\,dt = F(x^2) - F(x)$. Thus, $\dfrac{d}{dx}\displaystyle\int_{x}^{x^2}\dfrac{t}{\ln t}\,dt = \dfrac{d}{dx}[F(x^2) - F(x)]$.

Can you compute this? Remember that $F'(t) = \dfrac{t}{\ln t}$. Also, don't forget the Chain Rule.

Comment: So will the answer just be $\frac{d}{dx}2F(x^2) - \frac{t}{ln t}$
I kind of don't know much about the fundamental theorem...

Comment: No. First of all, the answer should only depend on $x$. Second, note that $\dfrac{d}{dx}[F(x^2)-F(x)] = \dfrac{d}{dx}F(x^2) - \dfrac{d}{dx}F(x)$. Can you differentiate each term? The first term requires the chain rule. The second term is straightforward.

Comment: I created a hint and you answered the question! Slow iPhones! Great answer though.

Comment: Is F(x) the same thing as $\frac{x}{ln(x)}$?

Comment: No, but $\dfrac{d}{dx}F(x) = F'(x) = \dfrac{x}{\ln x}$.

Comment: so then it should be.. $\frac{2x}{lnx} - \frac{x}{lnx}$ right?

Comment: That's not quite right. Let's first write things in terms of $F$. $\dfrac{d}{dx}[F(x^2)-F(x)] = F'(x^2) \cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}[x^2] - F'(x) = F'(x^2) \cdot 2x - F'(x)$ (using the chain rule). Now apply the fact that $F'(x) = \dfrac{x}{\ln x}$.

Comment: The only part I am confused about is that if $F'(x) = \frac{x}{lnx}$ how do I know what $F'(x^2)$ is?

Comment: $F'$ is the function that sends the number $t$ to the number $\frac{t}{\ln t}$. This is written as $F'(t) = \frac{t}{\ln t}$ (1). So, if you want to find $F'(x^2)$, replace all the $t$'s in (1) with $x^2$. That's how functions work.

Comment: So then $F'(x^2) = \frac{2x^3}{lnx^2}$

Comment: No, $F'(x^2) = \frac{x^2}{\ln(x^2)}$. However, $\frac{d}{dx}F(x^2) = 2x \cdot F'(x^2) = \frac{2x^3}{\ln(x^2)}$. The latter might be what you meant to write.

Comment: yes. so the answer should be ....... $\frac{2x^3}{ln(x^2)}-\frac{x}{ln(x)}$

Comment: Yes, although you might want to simplify $\ln(x^2) = 2\ln x$ (since we have to have $x > 0$).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)